# Xcodebuild calling test but never running

Tags: xcodebuild

I'm trying to run tests with the xcodebuild command line in this way ("Ink" is my project):

```
xcodebuild test -target "Ink" -sdk iphonesimulator TEST_AFTER_BUILD=YES "VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7 i386" -arch i386
```

but the command prompt give me the result:

```
unsupported build action 'test' - ** TEST FAILED **
```

What command is missing?

Comment: Do your project have multiple targets ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the command You try to run is badly ordered (the action You want to execute should always be at the end), try:

```
xcodebuild -target "Ink" -sdk iphonesimulator TEST_AFTER_BUILD=YES "VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7 i386" -arch i386 clean test
```

I also suppose it may be simplified to:

```
xcodebuild -target "Ink" -sdk iphonesimulator clean test
```

Which version of xcodebuild You use? Prior to 5.0 it was impossible to execute test action from command line.